# how to create a list/array of number's signs from a list of numbers

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of numbers:

```
n =  [ 1.2,0,-0.5,0.3,0,-0.8]
```

I want to create a numpy array using the above that only holds the sign of the numbers, result should be:

```
s = [1,0,-1,1,0,-1]
```

I can create this with a loop:

```
s= np.zeros(n.shape[0])    
for i in range (n.shape[0]):
    if n[i]>0: s[i]=1
    if n[i]<0: s[i]=-1
```

Is there a way to use list comprehension with numpy arrays that can do the same with high performance?

Comment: You can use `numpy.sign`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using numpy, a better solution is to use numpy.sign():

```
import numpy as np
s = np.sign(n)
```

This will give you a numpy array.

> array([ 1.,  0., -1.,  1.,  0., -1.])

To convert this floating point result to int, you may use:

```
s.astype(np.int)
```

If you want to convert it back to python list:

```
s_list = s.tolist()
```

You can do the above in one line as:

```
s = np.sign(n).astype(np.int).tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

The np.sign answer seems the best way, but if you want to code something, I feel like this should be pretty quick:

```
import numpy as np

def get_signs(array_of_numbers):
    f = lambda x: x and (1, -1)[x < 0]
    return np.fromiter((f(item) for item in array_of_numbers), array_of_numbers.dtype)
```